# Understanding practice exam about Agda

Tags: programming-languages, agda, agda-mode

I am going through my practice exam for Programming language Foundations using agda and it has the following question:

You are given the following Agda declaration:

```
data Even : N → Set where
 ezero : Even 0
 esuc : { n : N }  → Even n  → Even (2+ n)
```

Assume that the standard library of natural numbers has been imported. Answer the following questions:

a)What is the type of `ezero`?

b)Are there any terms of type `Even 1`?

c)How many terms are of type `Even 2`? List them

d)Describe one potential problem that might occur if we change the return type of esuc to be `Even (n+2)` instead of `Even (2+n)`.

We're not provided a solution manual. The question seems pretty basic but  I am not sure about any of these.I think the answer to the first three are:

a) Set

b) No terms of type Even 1

c) One term of type Even 2

d) don't know

Answers to these questions along with a brief explanation would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the type of `ezero`?

The type of the data constructor `ezero` can be read from the data declaration: `ezero : Even 0` states that it has type `Even 0`.

> Are there any terms of type `Even 1`?

No there aren't any. This can be seen by a case distinction: if there were a term then it'd start with either one of the two constructors. And because these have specific return indices, they'd have to unify with `1`.

- `ezero` would enforce `1 = 0`
- `esuc` would mean that there is an n such that `1 = 2+ n`

Both of these situations are impossible.

> How many terms are of type Even 2? List them

There is exactly one: `esuc ezero`. With a reasoning similar to the one in the previous question, we can prove that `ezero` and `esuc (esuc p)` (for some `p`) won't do.

> Describe one potential problem that might occur if we change the return type of `esuc` to be `Even (n+2)` instead of `Even (2+n)`.

Consider the proof `plus-Even : {m n : N} → Even m → Even n → Even (m + n)`. Because `(+)` is defined by induction on its first argument, you won't be able to immediately apply `esuc` in the step case. You are going to need to use rewriting to reorganize the type of the goal from `Even ((m +2) + n)` (or `Even (m + (n +2))` depending on which argument you perform induction on) to `Even ((m + n) +2)` beforehand.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers with great explanation.